# Respawning in video games like counter strike?

Tags: halal-haram

I play some games like PUBG etc. In these games there are options of like TEAM DEATH MATCH(TDM).When we die we respawn again. I really don't believe that in real life something like this can happen. But I heard some Muslim apologists said that Bringing people back to life is impossible so in video games this is not permissable to bring someone back to life. I agree with this statement. But what I am asking is we just respawns  again till 40 minutes are covered. And the team with most number of kills are won. So, does this respawning in videogames also come under bringing people back to life?

Answer (score 1):

I don’t think it does to be frank.
It’s a video game, it’s programmed by humans. If anyone were to code something, they can simply create it. So for your game, they obviously had coded it so players can respawn. Your game is fictional. It’s not reality.

However, this is completely different from trying to revive someone from the dead in real life. If that were the case, **then it would.**

But since it’s a game, it’s not real but just programmed, **no it wouldn’t**.

What you’re asking is basically something like, “in my game, we can’t pray. Does this fall under the same logic as not praying to Allah?”

Comment: Thank you. Just one more thing. In this game when someone runs out of HP. He can just crawl till all of its HP is ended. But we have the option to revive them. Is it okay? Keep in mind, he is not dead. He is just injured!

Comment: @SohailMir Again, it’s just a game, not reality.

Answer (score 0):

Everything that is instructed to us in Quran refers to our actions and doing in our real-life not any sort of video game as everything there is fake.